# Using Flow with ImmutableJs Record - Missing type annotation for `Values`

Tags: javascript, flowtype, immutable.js

I'm getting this flow error:

```
[Flow]

alertModal: RecordFactory<AlertModalState>
Missing type annotation for `Values`. `Values` is a type parameter declared in function type [1] and was implicitly instantiated at call of `Record` [2]. (References: [1] [2])
```

on this code:

```
export const makeFormControls = Record({
  alertModal: new alertModal()
})
```

Here is all the code involved:

```
//@flow
import type { RecordOf } from 'immutable'
import { Record } from 'immutable'


export type AlertModalState = {
  isOpen: boolean,
  title: string,
  message: string,
  height: number,
  hasYesNo: boolean,
  yesFunction: string
}

export const alertModal: RecordFactory<AlertModalState> = Record({
  isOpen: false,
  title: '',
  message: '',
  height: 0,
  hasYesNo: false,
  yesFunction: ''
})

export type AlertModalRecord = RecordOf<AlertModalState>



type FormControlsProps = {
  alertModal: AlertModalRecord
}

export const makeFormControls = Record({
  alertModal: new alertModal()
})

export type FormControls = RecordOf<FormControlsProps>
```

Why is flow complaining there is some `Values` param declared and implicitly instantiated?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading Immutable js from 4.0.0-rc.9 to 4.0.0-rc.12 fixed this.